# How & Where to Compute Views on Sonar

Tags: sonarqube

I am working with `Sonar3.7.4`. I have installed the views plugin but my Views column is EMPTY in the dashboard. i came to know views need to be computed. but I don't know how to compute the view `sonar-runner views`. Kindly help me on this.

Comment: What do you mean by "my Views column is EMPTY"? What version of the Views plugin are your running? Does the "sonar-runner views" command succeed?

Comment: i cant see any code quality reports when I select views. if I select project I can see all the reports. im using 2.2.2 version for views plugin. answering ur last question ...I really dono where to give "sonar-runner views" command.

Comment: If you don't run "sonar-runner views", your views are not computed, that's why no report is displayed. To run "sonar-runner views" please check http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Runner